# vb.net radiobutton progromatically setting 'Checked' and not cause 'Click' event

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am loading a form with values from stored settings from the registry

Typically : 
            If sFormat = TG_ReportFormatDft Then
                RadioButton1.Checked = True
                ........
            Else
                RadioButton2.Checked = True
                ..........
            End If

TG_ReportFormatDft is a string constant and is of no significance.  The radio buttons are grouped correctly and manually clicked behave correctly.

Later in the procedure I check if there has been a manual change :

```
'Follow what the user is doing
Private Sub RadioButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.Click
    msReports_Format2 = TG_ReportFormatDft
    DoButtons(True)
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.Click
    msReports_Format2 = TG_ReportFormatAlt
    DoButtons(True)
End Sub
```

Imagine my surprise when these downstream subroutines are triggered without a mouse click.  It would appear that :
       RadioButton1.Checked = True    --- triggers the mouse click event.

I can understand an 'On Change' event but the mouse click has not happened.

How can I prevent this 'click' event from propagating ?

Comment: I don't get it. You "...check if there has been a manual change" with the event handlers? And what is `DoButtons`? Whatever the issue, databinding would probably help as your model would raise propertychanged events.

Comment: You have to set the Click Event Handler after you load your defaults from registry. So not via the designer, but with code like `AddHandler RadioButton1.Click, AddressOf RadioButton1_Click`

Comment: It is not exactly obvious why this is a problem, it shouldn't be.  A simple solution is to add a `IgnoreClick As Boolean` variable to your class.

Comment: Could not re-create the issue.  RadioButton1.Checked = True did NOT trigger the mouse click event.

Comment: @dbasnett I could reproduce the issue. .NET 4.5.2 VS 2017.

Comment: Hi All;  In my mystification regarding MouseClick event triggering events, I forgot that I could disable any event using   RemoveHandler ----- and then AddHandler after the programmatic update of the radio buttons has been performed.  It all works perfectly fine now but I am still mystified why a mouse event would be triggered in the first place.

Comment: To Crowcoder.  Thank you, every Question and Reply is valuable,  The DoButtons sub is just a simple mechanism the change the buttons (not radiobuttons) on the form.  If the user has made radiobutton changes then I need to allow "Apply - Cancel"  rather than just "OK" to close the form without change.  My apologies for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a class level boolean variable "ClickedFromCode". Now when you are setting the values from code set the boolean to true. See below sample code.

```
Private ClickedFromCode As Boolean

Private Sub Intialize

    ClickedFromCode = True
    If sFormat = TG_ReportFormatDft Then 
        RadioButton1.Checked = True 
    Else 
        RadioButton2.Checked = True
    End If
    ClickedFromCode = False

End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.Click
    If ClickedFromCode Then 
        Return
    End If
    msReports_Format2 = TG_ReportFormatDft
    DoButtons(True)
End Sub

Private Sub RadioButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.Click
    If ClickedFromCode Then 
        Return
    End If
    msReports_Format2 = TG_ReportFormatAlt
    DoButtons(True)
End Sub
```